# How to retrieve all child components of a component in angular

Tags: angular

I have an Angular Component and I need to get all the child components of this component. How can this be done?

Comment: It would be good if you can provide more information, of what you are up to as part of your functionality?

Comment: I'm going to disable all the components that are on the page. These components are not within the form tag. All the components used in an interface are implemented.

Comment: using the @viewChildren let you retrieve all children's component but you have to specify a component type, afaik you can't retrieve just all children as you like

Comment: You can, just need to query by template variable identifier instead of component name, and change the QueryList type to <any>

Comment: The way I do stuff like this this is to add a boolean @Input() disable property to the components. It is up to the component to disable itself if this is set.

Answer (score 11):

One of possible solutions (may be there is a better one), is to use [`ViewChildren`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren), and this way you will get the access to all child components with specified name:

```
export class YourComponent {
  @ViewChildren(ChildComponentFoo) private _childrenFoo: QueryList<ChildComponentFoo>;
  @ViewChildren(ChildComponentBar) private _childrenBar: QueryList<ChildComponentBar>;

  /* ... */
}
```

Here is an example: [**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mltuej?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 7):

The previously-posted solution with ViewChildren will do the trick if you individually import and name each Component you want to query. An alternative, if you don't want to be concerned with what specific type the component is, is to give the same template variable to each component you eventually want to access.

```
<component1 #disabler></component1>
<component2 #disabler></component2>
<component3 #disabler></component3>
```

Then you can use ViewChildren and QueryList with type any

```
@ViewChildren('disabler') mycomponents: QueryList<any>;
```

You could also use contentchildren if the components are transcluded

```
@ContentChildren('disabler') mycomponents: QueryList<any>;
```

From here there are several approaches, but I would just give each of these components an identically named method that disables them.

```
this.mycomponents.forEach((element)=>{
     element.disable();
  })
```

They don't necessarily all have to have the same method with the same name, it just makes it simpler to iterate through them all programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this does not help me

Comment: Care to actually explain why? Its hard to help when your question and comments are so vague. You'd get more helpful answers if you actually posted some code, and told us what you've tried etc. Instead of a single sentence requirement :p

Comment: Because his question is clear? He needs all components, not disabler? Without having to be looking for a specific component, he just need all components.

Comment: OP explains in a comment on a different answer that he does indeed want to disable them.

Comment: Also this does not work if your children components are being dinamically added/removed.